# How can I remove empty space at the end of each line inside python tkinter ScrolledText widget?

Tags: python, tkinter

How can I remove empty space at the end of each line inside tkinter Scrolledtext widget ?

INPUT

> txt files that do not have empty space at the end of each line.

CODE

```
def openCommand():
        ftypes = [('Text files', '*.txt')] # allow only txt files
        filePath = tkFileDialog.askopenfile(parent=root,mode='rb',title=' Select a file', filetypes = ftypes)
        if filePath != None:
            contents = str(filePath.read()).strip()
            contents = contents.rstrip()
            contents = contents.lstrip()
            textPad.insert('1.0',contents.strip())
```

OUTPUT

Upon insert the file contents, in textpad:

```
textPad = ScrolledText(root, width=100, height=30, undo=True)
textPad.pack()
```

I will see an empty space at the end of each line.

NOTE

I have tried all related to Python string trimming.

Answer (score 0):

problem solved.
I've replaced the obj "tkFileDialog.askopenfile" with "tkFileDialog.Open".

Answer (score 0):

To answer your original question: I am 99% sure you are running on Windows and that your text file lines end with `\r\n`.  When you open in binary mode, you are asking Python to *not* replace `\r\n` with `\n`.  However, you *need* that replacement. Tk displays control chars other than `\n` as blank spaces.  This is the only way I can think of to have blanks magically appear.

From your use of `tkFileDialog`, I assume you are using 2.x.  I don't remember if 'r' gets you the line ending translation (I think it may) or if you need 'rU'.  In any case, tk does the translations when *it* reads the file.

Your repeated stripping of the entire file is useless and unneeded.